# Start script on linux startup

Tags: linux, yocto

I try to execute a java application at startup in a yocto based linux device. I added a script at `/etc/init.d/etic` and made it executable. If I call at the shell `/etc/init.d/etic start` or `/etc/init.d/etic stop` the application is started an stopped as expected. Then I called on the shell `update-rc.d etic defaults` and the symlinks were created. According to what I found on the web, this should be enough, but somehow the application is not started. What did I miss? How could I check what is going wrong or is there any minimal example which should work which I can try to extend?

Comment: If the symlinks are created, that should be enough. Try to have your init-script log what's happening. Maybe the PATH is not set correctly / fully when run using sysvinit?

Comment: Does the app have a UI?

Comment: @Anders Which log do you mean, the one from my etic script? For the path I added `PATH=$PATH:/usr/java/bin` to my script as java is used.

Comment: @jku No there is now UI, the device has no graphical user interface.

Comment: Well, you can log to syslog using eg `logger ....` from your start script. Another option would be to start the script by redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` for the script to a file, e.g. `/tmp/etic.log`, just to be sure to catch all possible error messages. Does your application require any other environment variables being set (eg `JAVA_HOME`), that might not be set when run in your script? Dump the environment from the script and compare it with your interactive environment when it works.

Comment: Thank you for your help Anders! With `logger ...` I could find the error. The path to my java application was not correct. I'm not sure why it worked when I called it from the shell with `/etc/init.d/etic start`, so I was assuming the path was correct.

Comment: Adding a short answer for you to accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, often such issues are due to a different environment when executing the start script by hand, as compared to when it's being run from the init system. For instance, your `.profile` and `.bashrc` won't have been sourced, when running from the init system.

You can use eg `logger` to easily log things from your init-script, and this rather easily find out what goes wrong.